# Resend (bounce) a message with attachment in mailx (or any other tools)

Tags: linux, shell-script, email

I've got a mail folder which contains a unique e-mail containing several attachment. I'd like to script the resending of the email as verbatim as possible.

If I write

```
cat tosend | mailx some-address@some.site
```

Then the e-mail is forwarded as a text content, the attachment being unreadable for the mailer. Is there a way to resent the using a command-line script, while keeping it's attachment structure or should I extract all the attachment and rebuild the email from them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sendmail(1)` and `formail(1)` (from the `procmail` package), rather than `mailx(1)`:

```bash
formail -s sendmail -oem -oi some-address@some.site <mail-folder
```

The point of `formail(1)` is just to split the folder into individual messages, you can omit it if you have a single message to bounce.